# Reading from a file,using headers and cpp's

Tags: c++, ifstream

Ok, so I have a 3 level inheritance tree of vehicles. The leaf classes (the last ones down the tree) are six. I want to make a function that will read from a .txt file, and then assign the information to different variables (e.g. the file will contain 2006 Toyota Supra Diesel and these will be assigned to `year`, `brand`, `model`, `fuel_type`). Actually I managed to do this, but afterwards when I split my code into .h and .cpp files the function stopped working.

```
void Cars::txt_input()
{
    getline(file,input);          //This is in the .cpp file for one of the 
    year = atoi(input.c_str());   //child classes.
    getline(file,input);
    brand = input;
    getline(file,input);
    model = input;
    getline(file,input);
    passenger_capacity = atoi(input.c_str());
    getline(file,input);
    engine_power = atoi(input.c_str());
    getline(file,input);
    max_speed = atoi(input.c_str());    
    getline(file,input);
    fuel_type = input;
    getline(file,input);
    wheel_drive = input;
    getline(file,input);
    average_cons = atoi(input.c_str());
    getline(file,input);
    number_doors = atoi(input.c_str());
    getline(file,input);
    cType = input;
    getline(file,input);
    price = atoi(input.c_str());
}
```

In my main() I have declared `ifstream file("vehicles.txt")` and `string input`, which worked fine before splitting the code. Also,I have created the `ifstream file` and `string input` variables as protected members of the base class, otherwise it won't compile because it doesn't find any file and input variables to work with. However, now it seems the function does not take the variables from `main()` at all, and just fills all the objects' fields with 0 or N/A (according to the constructor.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    if(i<4) 
        vehicles.push_back(new Cars());
        vehicles[vehicles.size()-1]->txt_input();
    }
    if(i==4 || i==5)
    {
        vehicles.push_back(new Bus());
        vehicles[vehicles.size()-1]->txt_input();
    }
    //...
}
```

This is how I create the objects in my `main()`. As I said, when I had all the code in my Main.cpp it worked perfectly. Also,I tried passing `(ifstream file,string input)` as arguments to the `txt_input()` function but it produces an error C2248. This is my first-time post,sorry if there is any ambiguity. I'll provide more code/information if needed.

```
class Vehicles
{
public:

    Vehicles();

    virtual void txt_input();
    virtual void user_input();
    virtual void output();

    void red_output();

    int getPC();
    int getPrice();
    string getBrand();

    void open_file();

protected:
    string brand, model, type;
    int year, passenger_capacity, price;
    double engine_power, max_speed;
    ifstream file;
    string input;
};
```

This is the parent class.

Comment: where are `file` and `input` defined ? Are they member of `Cars` or globals ?

Comment: Where and how is your ifstream file declared and defined? A much cleaner setup would be to pass the input stream to your txt_input functions.

Comment: @Jarod42 file and input are defined in the base class.I just edited the post,sorry.

Comment: @heinrichj the ifstream file is only declared in the base class.How could I pass the stream to the txt_input functions?When I tried it gives me a C2248,as I said. Also,the ifstream file is only declared,it does not actually open a file.

Comment: Is txt_input declared virtual in your base class? How is the "file" member initialized? Maybe it's easier if you show the full code of the base class and one of the concrete classes...

Comment: Yes,it is virtual through the inheritance tree.File is not initialized,since I don't know where to do this (if I do it in the constructor it's gonna read from the beginning of the file each time).That's pretty much all the code relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem, according to comments, is that your variable `file` is now a member of `Vehicles` unrelated with the previous ifstream in your main...

So the following may help:

```
/*virtual*/ void Vehicles::txt_input(std::istream& file)
{
    std::string input;    

    getline(file, input);
    year = atoi(input.c_str());
    getline(file, input);
    brand = input;
    // And so on... 

}
```

And so your loop becomes :

```
std::ifstream file("vehicles.txt");
for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++) {
    Cars* cars = new Cars();
    cars->txt_input(file);
    vehicles.push_back(cars);
}
for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++) {
    Bus* bus = new Bus();
    bus->txt_input(file);
    vehicles.push_back(bus);
}
```

Comment: Yes,dude,that did it.Thank you a lot. Just some quick questions:
1.Why do we pass it as istream instead of ifstream(like the variable type)?
2.Why do we have to pass it by reference?

Comment: `istream` is more generic, And so, you may pass `std::cin` for example

Answer (score 0):

You have set variable `file` in `main` but using the member variable also named `file` which is not being set to `vehicles.txt`. One way is to make the constructor take the file name as a parameter.

E.g. code - not compiled
Constructor

`Cars::Cars(const ifstream& if)
: file(if)
{
}`

When adding it to the vector
`vehicles.push_back(new Cars(file)); // this is the file defined in main set to "vehicles.txt"`

Note: Use conventions when naming your class member variables (e.g. mFile, m_file, _file) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes,the method is complete. When everything was in Main.cpp I had this function, and I had globally defined ifstream file("vehicles.txt") and string input. And then,as you see, during the for loop, different objects were pushed into the vector, and their txt_input() function was carried out. However,when I split the code into cpp's and headers, it seems that the function is only looking for such variables in the inheritance tree itself. That is why I defined in the base class ifstream file; and string input; Nothing more.

Comment: Class "Vehicles" is a parent of "Land" "Sea" "Air". "Land" is a parent of "Cars" "Bus". "Sea" is a parent of "Cruise_Ship" " "Yacht". "Air" is a parent of "Airplane" "Helicopter".

Comment: It's important that you show us the base class definition and the code which initializes `file`. Also you can check for any error being set by `getline` to get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I will look into naming conventions in the future.